# Python multiple stock price tracker

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to create 1 minute stock price tracker server for a set of stocks in python. I have written a multi-threaded python program which calls my price tracker function for each stock in the list. This causes CPU utilisation on my computer to reach ~100% and makes everything very slow.

Could you please suggest a way or any other tool that I should use.

P.S. I have tried mutli-processing as well.

```py
    def f(x):
        print("Starting process : " + str(x))
        time.sleep(5)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        while (True):
            km = datetime.now().minute
            ks = datetime.now().second
            if km % 1 == 0 and ks == 1:
                print("=>S===> / km = " + str(km) + " | " + " ks = " + str(ks))
                for x in range(20):
                    p = Process(target=f, args=(x, ))
                    p.start()
                km = datetime.now().minute
                ks = datetime.now().second
                print("=>E===> / km = " + str(km) + " | " + " ks = " + str(ks))
                time.sleep(1)
                p.join()
```

This is my code. function f is were I am planning to do calculations at the start of every minute and it should create separate processes for n number of stocks (20 in code example)

Edit : (1) I have done below changes and thought it will sync with clock, However, the clock and prints from below code does not match. There is always a delay of 6 secs.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time

firstRun = True


def f(x):
    print("Starting process : " + str(x))
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Ending process : " + str(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while (True):
        ks = datetime.now().second
        print("//////////////////////////////////////////// Delay in secs : " +
              str(ks))
        if (firstRun):
            ks = datetime.now().second
            print("First Run - Sleeping for " + str(60 - ks) + " secs.")
            firstRun = False
            time.sleep(60 - ks)
        else:
            print("Subsequent runs ...")
            ks = datetime.now().second
            #print("=>S===> / ks = " + str(ks))
            for x in range(20):
                p = Process(target=f, args=(x, ))
                p.start()
            ks = datetime.now().second
            #print("=>E===> ks = " + str(ks))
            p.join()
            print("Will sleep for " + str(60 - ks) + " secs.")
            time.sleep(60 - ks)
```

Output :

```py
//////////////////////////////////////////// Delay in secs : 6
Subsequent runs ...
Starting process : 2
Starting process : 0
Starting process : 1
Starting process : 3
Starting process : 5
Starting process : 4
Starting process : 14
Starting process : 9
Starting process : 15
Starting process : 11
Starting process : 17
Starting process : 6
Starting process : 8
Starting process : 12
Starting process : 18
Starting process : 16
Starting process : 13
Starting process : 10
Starting process : 19
Starting process : 7
Ending process : 2
Ending process : 0
Ending process : 1
Ending process : 3
Ending process : 5
Ending process : 4
Ending process : 14
Ending process : 9
Ending process : 15
Ending process : 11
Ending process : 17
Ending process : 6
Ending process : 12
Ending process : 8
Ending process : 18
Ending process : 16
Ending process : 13
Ending process : 10
Ending process : 19
Ending process : 7
Will sleep for 54 secs.
```

Comment: Adding in code and/or showing what research you've done is customary.

Comment: The only time you ever `sleep` is once per minute.  The rest of the time is spent in a spin loop, of course you're going to be at 100% CPU.

Comment: All integers mod 1 are 0, so `km % 1 == 0` isn't doing anything for you.
If you want to execute every minute, you might want to `sleep(60)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, could you please suggest a way to avoid that ?

Comment: @Josh, on that case if my function f runs for say 10 sec then by the time child processes join main process total time elapsed will be 70 sec. Is not it ?

Comment: Move your `sleep` so it's not inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using "Schedule" library :

```py
import schedule

.
.
.
schedule.every(1).minutes.at(":00").do(run_threaded, job)
```